# Formatted String Literals

Tags: python-3.x

Why one formatted String literals is able to print without print() but the other not?

```
>> price = 11.23
>> f"Price in Euro: {price}"

>> for article in ["bread", "butter", "tea"]:
       print(f"{article:>10}:")
```

Comment: Do you execute this in an interactive session or is it run as a script?

Comment: Jupiter notebook interactive session

Comment: Interactive sessions print the result of the last expression. A format string is an expression, a for loop is not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 1):

Interactive sessions print the result of the last top-level statement. A format string is an expression and thus has a result, but a for loop is not and produces no result to display.

```
>>> 3      # expression
3
>>> a = 3
>>> a      # expresion 
3
>>> a + 4  # expression 
7
>>> if a:
...     9
>>> f"{a}"   # expression 
3
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear what you want to do with your code, but this should work

```py
for article in ['bread', 'butter']:
   print(f"{article}")
```

Can you please properly format your code and edit your question?

Comment: I find it hard to believe you actually understood what is wrong here or what is the actual question...

Comment: That's why I wrote, "It's pretty unclear what you want to do with your code". Sadly I am 5 short of the amount of rep necessary to comment otherwise I would have.

Comment: Point is, if it is *pretty unclear what you're asking for*, I find it hard to be able to actually answer...

Comment: My question is why one statement is giving output without print function while the second one requires a print() fun